# Mothers name is different in Child passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens

Iam from India. My name is RAJUCHAMBANNA VEERABHADRAPPA YARADAL and I have a valid indian passport. My wife's passport is her maiden name even after marriage as PRATIBHA KHODANAPUR.

Now I have a Child passport wherein the mothers name is PRATIBHA RAJUCHAMBANNA YARADAL which does not match with her passport. Because the birth certificate shows name of mother as PRATIBHA RAJUCHAMBANNA YARADAL.

Can I get the passport with short name of mother as PRATIBHA in Child passport and keeping her name is passport as PRATIBHA KHODANAPUR? Hope there should not be any problem in this arrangement.
Please suggest the best possible solution to have uniformity in all documents.

Comment: I don't believe the Nationality makes any difference with regards to the above duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelDodd but this question is rather different: it is asking how to achieve uniformity in the documents, not how to cope with the differences when traveling.  RajuChambanna Yaradal, what does your marriage certificate say?  Was your wife's name legally changed? If so, it seems the solution would be to get her a new passport.